# Cannot access Minio After Helm Installation

Tags: kubernetes, helm, minio

I tried installing Minio via the helm chart.  You can see my `values.yml` below.  I set the accessKey and secretKey myself.  But after I bring up the deployment, I cannot log in.  When I go to the webpage and try to, it says

> The access key ID you provided does not exist in our records

How can I access my server after installing via helm?

```
# helm install --name minio --namespace wfs -f wfs/minio/values.yml stable/minio

accessKey: <redacted>
secretKey: <redacted>

ingress:
  enabled: true
  hosts:
    - minio.example.com
replicas: 1
persistence:
  size: 1Gi
  storageClass: slipspace
tls:
  enabled: false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab your key and password by reading the secret keys and decode them. 
In my example we have the following secret created by the installer:

```
$ kubectl get secrets 
NAME                                TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
crusty-mongoose-minio               Opaque                                2      15m
crusty-mongoose-minio-token-jqbcb   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3      11m
```

You can check your encoded key by running:

```
$ kubectl get secret --namespace default crusty-mongoose-minio -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  accesskey: bXlhY2Nlc3NrZXk=
  secretkey: bXlzZWNyZXRrZXk=   
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-10-31T14:27:52Z"
  labels:
    app: minio
    chart: minio-2.5.16
    heritage: Tiller
    release: crusty-mongoose
  name: crusty-mongoose-minio
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "358025"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/crusty-mongoose-minio
  uid: af8ed190-4e59-49df-b584-824a4eb14439
type: Opaque
```

From here you can see my encoded access and secure keys:

```
accesskey: bXlhY2Nlc3NrZXk=
secretkey: bXlzZWNyZXRrZXk=
```

Now that we have it we can decode using the following command:

```
$ echo bXlhY2Nlc3NrZXk= | base64 --decode
mysecretkey
 echo bXlzZWNyZXRrZXk= | base64 --decode
mysecretkey
```

Optionally you can grab using the following command:

```
$ kubectl get secret --namespace default fashionable-elk-minio -o jsonpath="{.data.accesskey}" |e 
myaccesskey
$ kubectl get secret --namespace default fashionable-elk-minio -o jsonpath="{.data.secretkey}" | base64 --decode 
mysecretkey
```

Comment: @cclloyd, these steps helped you to get to the solution?